# How can I solve this problem with DataBInding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In this project I want to create a Pixel Coloring book.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColorMatrix}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <pxl:Pixel 
                                Style="{StaticResource Pixel}"
                                PrimaryColor="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

`ColoringBookView.xaml`

This is just a  view of the Color[][] array.

ColorMatrix is Color[][] type

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is System.Drawing.Color drawingColor)
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(drawingColor.A, drawingColor.R, drawingColor.G, drawingColor.B);
        }
        return Colors.Black; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`ColoreConverter.cs`

```
public class Pixel : CheckBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PrimaryColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Pixel));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AccentColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AccentColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Pixel));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDrawedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsDrawed", typeof(bool), typeof(Pixel));

    public Color PrimaryColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(PrimaryColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public Color AccentColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(AccentColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AccentColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public bool IsDrawed
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDrawedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDrawedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

`Pixel.cs`

This is a CustomControl for WPF.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:pxl="clr-namespace:PXL.Core.Theme"
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PXL.Core.Converters">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type pxl:Pixel}" x:Key="Pixel">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type pxl:Pixel}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding PrimaryColor}"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock Text="Pixel" Background="{TemplateBinding PrimaryColor}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding PrimaryColor}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`Pixel.xaml`

I have troubles with databinding, but I don't understand what's wrong.

The TextBlock.Background and TextBlock.Foreground in Pixel.xaml doesn't change.

Comment: You must wrap the `ItemsPresenter` of the `ControlTemplate` into a `ScrollViewer` and not the complete `ItemsControl` (this results in a different scroll behavior - you want to scroll the *content* or items of the control and not the control itself). I recommend to use the `ListBox` instead: it is an extended `ItemsControl` that comes with a scroll viewer and other performance enhancements. For performance reasons, you should also not bind to an array. Instead bind to an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: The TextBlock color attributes won't change as there is nothing to trigger them to change. Do you expect them to change dynamically? Your ColorConverter always returns the color Black (I assume you are not using System.Drawing.Color in your code - you shouldn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Background` and `Foreground` properties of the `TextBlock` can only be set to `System.Windows.Media.Brush` values.

You cannot bind these to a `System.Windows.Media.Color` or `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: I added converter from System.Windows.Media.Color to System.Windows.Media.Brush, but it don't change anything. The rectangle is always transparent

Comment: Converter? You should change the type of your properties.